# Serialize list of objects to properties of object

Tags: c#, json

Is there any way to serialize collection of objects to json object properties? I would like to use newtonsoft json.

Let's suppouse I have:

```
class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item { Name = "a", Prop1 = "123" },
    new Item { Name = "b", Prop1 = "456" },
    new Item { Name = "c", Prop1 = "789" }
}
```

After serialization I would like to have:

```
{
  'a' : { 'prop1': '123' }
  'b' : { 'prop1': '345' }
  'c' : { 'prop1': '789' }
}
```

Thanks for any help
IT Man

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Serializing a Collection of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463548/c-sharp-serializing-a-collection-of-objects)

Comment: Check this post out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110724/serializing-a-list-to-json or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904752/serializing-a-list-of-object-using-json-net

Comment: Sure, transform it into a dictionary, then serialize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a Dictionary, JsonIgnore (from Newtonsoft.Json) and a camel case converter (from Newtonsoft.Json)

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QPtaD7)

```
public class Item
{
    // jsonignore is an attribute to ... ignore this in json
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var items = new List<Item>
    {
        new Item { Name = "a", Prop1 = "123" },
        new Item { Name = "b", Prop1 = "456" },
        new Item { Name = "c", Prop1 = "789" }
    };

    // we use a Dictionary as Amy propose in comment
    var obj = items.ToDictionary(x=> x.Name, x => x);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings 
    { 
        // we need this to use camel case
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
    });

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

output

```
{"a":{"prop1":"123"},"b":{"prop1":"456"},"c":{"prop1":"789"}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution should fit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom JsonConverter:

```
class ListOfItemsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(List<Item>));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject item = new JObject();

        foreach (var val in (value as List<Item>))
        {
            var internalItem = new JObject {new JProperty("prop1", val.Prop1)};
            item.Add(new JProperty(val.Name, internalItem));
        }

        item.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, new ListOfItemsConverter());
```