# Writing compact xml with XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter and a XmlDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, binary-xml

I want to write an xml document to disk in a compact format. To this end, I use the net framework method [`XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(Stream stream,IXmlDictionary dictionary)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366445%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This method writes a custom compact binary xml representation, that can later be read by `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryReader`. The method accepts an `XmlDictionary` that can contain common strings, so that those strings do not have to be printed in the output each time. Instead of the string, the dictionary index will be printed in the file. `CreateBinaryReader` can later use the same dictionary to reverse the process.

However the dictionary I pass is apparently not used. Consider this code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        XmlDictionary dict = new XmlDictionary();
        dict.Add("myLongRoot");
        dict.Add("myLongAttribute");
        dict.Add("myLongValue");
        dict.Add("myLongChild");
        dict.Add("myLongText");

        XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
        xdoc.Add(new XElement("myLongRoot",
                                new XAttribute("myLongAttribute", "myLongValue"),
                                new XElement("myLongChild", "myLongText"),
                                new XElement("myLongChild", "myLongText"),
                                new XElement("myLongChild", "myLongText")
                                ));

        using (Stream stream = File.Create("binaryXml.txt"))
        using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream, dict))
        {
            xdoc.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

The produced output is this (binary control characters not shown)

```
@
myLongRootmyLongAttribute˜myLongValue@myLongChild™
myLongText@myLongChild™
myLongText@myLongChild™
myLongText
```

So apparently the XmlDictionary has not been used. All strings appear in their entirety in the output, even multiple times.

This is not a problem limited to XDocument. In the above minimal example I used a XDocument to demonstrate the problem, but originally I stumbled upon this while using XmlDictionaryWriter in conjunction with a DataContractSerializer, as it is commonly used. The results were the same:

```
[Serializable]
public class myLongChild
{
    public double myLongText = 0;
}
...
using (Stream stream = File.Create("binaryXml.txt"))
using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream, dict))
{
    var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(myLongChild));
    dcs.WriteObject(writer, new myLongChild());
}
```

The resulting output did not use my XmlDictionary.

**How can I get XmlDictionaryWriter to use the suplied XmlDictionary?**

Or have I misunderstood how this works?

with the DataContractSerializer approach, I tried debugging the net framework code (*visual studio/options/debugging/enable net. framework source stepping*). Apparently the Writer does attempt to lookup each of the above strings in the dictionary, as expected. However the lookup fails in [line 356 of XmlbinaryWriter.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Xml/XmlBinaryWriter.cs,359), for reasons that are not clear to me.

Alternatives I have considered:

- There is an overload for XmlDictionaryWriter.CreatebinaryWriter, that also accepts a XmlBinaryWriterSession. The writer then adds any new strings it encounters into the session dictionary. However, **I want to only use a static dictionary for reading and writing, which is known beforehand**.
- I could wrap the whole thing into a `GzipStream` and let the compression take care of the multiple instances of strings. However, this would not compress the first instance of each string, and seems like a clumsy workaround overall.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a misunderstanding. `XmlDictionaryWriter` is primarily used for serialization of objects and it is child class of `XmlWriter`. `XDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter something)` takes `XmlWriter` as argument. The call `XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter` will create an instance of `System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeWriter` internally. This class has both methods for "regular" writing:

```
// override of XmlWriter
public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName)
{
  // plain old "xml" for me please
}
```

and for dictionary based approach:

```
// override of XmlDictionaryWriter
public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, XmlDictionaryString localName)
{
  // I will use dictionary to hash element names to get shorter output
}
```

The later is mostly used if you serialize object via `DataContractSerializer` (notice its method `WriteObject` takes argument of both `XmlDictionaryWriter` and `XmlWriter` type), while `XDocument` takes just `XmlWriter`.

As for your problem - if I were you I'd make my own `XmlWriter`:

```
class CustomXmlWriter : XmlWriter
{
  private readonly XmlDictionaryWriter _writer;
  public CustomXmlWriter(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
  {
    _writer = writer;
  }
  // override XmlWriter methods to use the dictionary-based approach instead
}
```

**UPDATE** (based on your comment)

If you indeed use `DataContractSerializer` you have few mistakes in your code.

1) POC classes have to be decorated with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attribute, the serialized value should be property and not field; also set namespace to empty value or you'll have to deal with namespaces in your dictionary as well. Like:

```
namespace  XmlStuff {
  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public class myLongChild
  {
    [DataMember]
    public double myLongText { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
  public class myLongRoot
  {
    [DataMember]
    public IList<myLongChild> Items { get; set; }
  }
}
```

2) Provide instance of session as well; for null session the dictionary writer uses default (`XmlWriter`-like) implementation:

```
// order matters - add new items only at the bottom
static readonly string[] s_Terms = new string[]
{
    "myLongRoot", "myLongChild", "myLongText", 
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "Items"
};

public class CustomXmlBinaryWriterSession : XmlBinaryWriterSession
{
  private bool m_Lock;
  public void Lock() { m_Lock = true; }

  public override bool TryAdd(XmlDictionaryString value, out int key)
  {
    if (m_Lock)
    {
      key = -1;
      return false;
    }

    return base.TryAdd(value, out key);
  }
}

static void InitializeWriter(out XmlDictionary dict, out XmlBinaryWriterSession session)
{
  dict = new XmlDictionary();
  var result = new CustomXmlBinaryWriterSession();
  var key = 0;
  foreach(var term in s_Terms)
  {
    result.TryAdd(dict.Add(term), out key);
  }
  result.Lock();
  session = result;
}

static void InitializeReader(out XmlDictionary dict, out XmlBinaryReaderSession session)
{
  dict = new XmlDictionary();
  var result = new XmlBinaryReaderSession();
  for (var i = 0; i < s_Terms.Length; i++)
  {
    result.Add(i, s_Terms[i]);
  }
  session = result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  XmlDictionary dict;
  XmlBinaryWriterSession session;
  InitializeWriter(out dict, out session);

  var root = new myLongRoot { Items = new List<myLongChild>() };
  root.Items.Add(new myLongChild { myLongText = 24 });
  root.Items.Add(new myLongChild { myLongText = 25 });
  root.Items.Add(new myLongChild { myLongText = 27 });

  byte[] buffer;
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    using (var writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateBinaryWriter(stream, dict, session))
    {
      var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(myLongRoot));
      dcs.WriteObject(writer, root);
    }
    buffer = stream.ToArray();
  }


  XmlBinaryReaderSession readerSession;
  InitializeReader(out dict, out readerSession);
  using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, false))
  {
    using (var reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateBinaryReader(stream, dict, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas(), readerSession))
    {
      var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(myLongRoot));
      var rootCopy = dcs.ReadObject(reader);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this with a DataContractSerializer before switching to XDocument; i just left it out of the minimal example because the results were exactly the same: with var dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyLongClass)); dcs.WriteObject(writer, new MyLongclass()); the dictionary is not used. Debugging showed that the dictionary-based methods of XmlBinaryNodeWriter were called, and the Writer attempted to look up values in the dictionary; however this lookup failed for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Regarding the `[DataContract]` attribute, I think you are mistaken here; DatacontractSerializer can actually serialize classes even if they only have the `[Serializable]` attribute, in that case it serializes private fields as well. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3156546/145999

Comment: Regarding the `XmlBinaryWriterSession`, yes, if I use one of those the output will not contain any strings. But that is independent on whether those strings are in the dictionary! 
Even with an empty dictionary, the DataContractSerializer will just fill the session dictionary on the fly. That means I cannot later deserialize the data without possessing the final session dictionary, which makes this approach not work for me. (ref. second-to-last paragraph of my question)

Comment: What I am really looking for is a way to make XmlDictionaryWriter and Reader use only my hardcoded dictionary, without generating a dynamic dictionary. Now it may be that this is not possible; as you said XmlBinaryWriter appears to not work properly without a session. But I cannot find anything in the docs that would prevent it from working thus, and the `CreateBinaryWriter()` call without a session but with a dict appears useless otherwise.

Comment: @HugoRune - and I though I've outlined it already :) I've update my code sample to contain read part as well.