# postshap: OnMethodBoundaryAspect and WebMethod

Tags: c#, web-services, postsharp, webmethod

I'm using PostSharp to add an aspect to a WebMethod.

Below is my aspect (it does nothing... doesn't want to compile):

```
public class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect, ISerializable
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

    }

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

And my webmethod looks like :

```
    [MyAspect]
    [WebMethod]
    public void MyWebMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
```

When I build the project, there is an error:

Erreur  346 PostSharp: Cannot serialize the aspects: Le type 'xxxx.MyAspect' dans l'assembly 'zzzzz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' n'est pas marqué comme sérialisable..   unknown_location    xxxxx

It tells me that my aspect is not tagged as serializable...

What can I do? FYI, I don't have any problem with such aspects in the rest of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the `Serializable` attribute to your `MyAspect`. So:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
```

Instead of inheriting the `ISerializable` interface. For the differences see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810974/what-is-the-point-of-the-iserializable-interface).