# MediaTypeFormatter for inner porperties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I understand using of MedaTypeFormatters to control serialization and deserialization.
But, what I am confused with is how to control serialization of some inner property.
I.E.
If I create class like this:

```
public class Employee {
  public Address Address {get;set;}
}
```

I understand I can create formatter and define

```
public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
{
  return type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Employee ));
}
```

.. and then override **WriteToStream** to set how is serialized but can I somehow have influence on **inner property** like **Address** in this case?

To be clear I am searching for solution to connect to Address type so it is serialized custom way every time it appears in serialization process as a root class or inner property.

Comment: You might want to implement `ISerializable` interface by the `Address` class.

Comment: Thanks, with this approach I can get something like : {Address: {Location: 'Massachusetts, Boston'}} but cannot {Address: 'Massachusetts, Boston'}... can I?

Comment: As it [said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810974/what-is-the-point-of-the-iserializable-interface), you can fully control the serialization process. You might want to try it.